# How to use PageTransitionsBuilder when navigating to a different screen?

Tags: flutter

```
final builder = OpenUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder();

Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: builder, // error
  ),
);
```

What I understand is, I can only setup `PageTransitionsBuilder` inside a `Theme`, is there any way to use it inside `Navigator`?

Comment: `PageTransitionsBuilder` is used by `PageTransitionsTheme` only, if you want to use it in `PageRouteBuilder` you would need to write some small builder wrapper

Comment: @pskink Got it sir, can you share some link or doc, where I can find how to wrap that?

Comment: `transitionsBuilder: (ctx, a1, a2, child) => builder.buildTransitions(route, ctx, a1, a2, child)`

Comment: this is just a workaround - instead you should write a class that extends `PageRouteBuilder` or `PageRoute` or `ModalRoute` - anyway, feel free to write a self-answer ;-)

Comment: @pskink Yes, I know those ways of extending `PageRoute`, `PageRouteBuilder` or even `ModalRoute`, but that way I'll have to provide Animation on my own, but this time I wanted to use built in animations provided by the team, so I thought of using one of them. And I just noticed one thing that I need to provide a `route` to the constructor, so at the end of the day I need one of the classes which extends `PageRoute` and other (mentioned before), seems like there is no way of doing it.

Comment: That worked sir, you're genius, now that you have written the entire code in comment, I really request you to copy and paste that in answer, please sir!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simple solution is a custom `PageRouteBuilder`:

```
class MyPageRouteBuilder<T> extends PageRouteBuilder<T> {
  final PageTransitionsBuilder pageTransitionsBuilder;

  MyPageRouteBuilder({
    @required RoutePageBuilder pageBuilder,
    @required this.pageTransitionsBuilder,
  }) : assert(pageTransitionsBuilder != null), super(pageBuilder: pageBuilder);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return pageTransitionsBuilder.buildTransitions(this, context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child);
  }
}
```

Here only `pageBuilder` is passed to `super()` but you can add any named parameter that `PageRouteBuilder` accepts (like `transitionDuration` for example)

Now, you can use it with:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MyPageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (ctx, a1, a2) => Page2(),
    pageTransitionsBuilder: OpenUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (ctx, a1, a2) => Screen2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (ctx, anim, a2, child) => FadeTransition(opacity: anim, child: child),
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
  ),
);
```

You can vary milliseconds time, as per your need in-app.

Comment: you said you wanna navigate to another screen and facing problem over it, also you have added you are getting error "transitionsBuilder: builder, // error". What I miss here please explain if you can

Comment: Please read the question carefully, I am not asking for `RouteTransitionsBuilder`, instead  `PageTransitionsBuilder`. There is a difference between the two. I want to use `PageTransitionsBuilder` in `Navigator`, possible?.

Comment: You may want to give a look at the comment from @pskink on the post.